# How should I use "just as .. so .." phrase

Tags: word-usage

I have not understood the usage of the phrase "just as .. so" yet.
When should I use it ? What is it meant for ?

Do the sentences have to be diferent in some way ?

> "Just as Roni wanted to see her again, so Bony wanted to see him"

There is no a difference between Roni and Bony. Both Roni and Bony wanted to see each other –

Comment: [***Just as** the French like their wine, **so** the English like their beer.*](http://www.urch.com/forums/english/1041-just-as-so-too.html) What aspect of the construction do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Just as we eat bread, the Chinese eat rice. = In the same way that we habitually eat bread, the Chinese habitually eat rice. The construction suggests a parallel between two things (we both habitually eat something) modified by a secondary difference (what is eaten is bread in our case or rice in the Chinese case).

Comment: In fact, I have understood  the meaning of the phrase but I haven't understand when I should use this . Should I use this in order to declare diffrences ?

Comment: Yes, I think you can. My answer shows that you may declare a difference within the context of a similarity. That is a more complicated thing to do than just to declare a difference. Sometimes you may wish to use the construction; sometimes not.

Comment: Do the sentences have to be diferent in some way ?
"Just as Roni wanted to see her again, so Bony wanted to see him" . There is no a real difference. Both Roni and Bony wanted to see each other @Anton

Comment: I understand your new example and it is correct. There does not HAVE to be an underlying difference, although I can still see  one in your example: He is looking at HER and she is looking at HIM. Men and women see each other differently. But I take your point entirely, as in "Just as he wanted to go to London, so did she."